# add class and keep checking rest of document

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, document

I am trying to add a class to a bold element only if the bold element does not already have the class specified.  Can someone please tell me what I am missing.  It stops running after it finds one that fails instead of checking each.

```
 if ($("font[size='3'] b").hasClass('dont_run')) {}
 else {$("font[size='3'] b").addClass('barcode_needed')
 };
```

Comment: FONT elements, fancy that! `:)`

Comment: Not an answer, but are you aware that the `<font>` tag has been deprecated for quite some time, and that `<b>`, having no semantics, should be used sparingly, if ever?

Comment: [Deprecated?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/font). [Meaningless?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/b) Never. ;p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('font[size="3"] b:not(.dont_run)').addClass('barcode_needed');
```

Using the [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector will achieve this easily.

Answer (score 2):

Couple things here. Is dont_run a class or a tag? if its a class it should look like this:

```
$("font[size='3'] b").hasClass('.dont_run')
```

second, do you plan on doing more in the if else statement? if not then you should use the shorthand version mentioned by Brad Christie